# How to get current seek position in YouTube?

Tags: angularjs, youtube-iframe-api

I am using the 'angualr-YouTube-embed' directive to embed a YouTube player in my Angular web app. In that I have to identify current seek position of the video which is playing. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Last I found a solution for this problem.

we can use `player.getCurrentTime()` to get the current seek position.

You can find details here: [YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)